# Android getItemId() return the same id many times in recyclerview

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, adapter

I'm trying to implement `setHasStableId(true)` in my application. When I override `getItemId()` method in my `RecyclerView` adapter in the following way :

```
override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long { position.hashCode().toLong()}
```

the application tells me that the same item id is being returned several times. Items are not being duplicated in the list, for the user everything is ok but I'm getting this error.

> Two different ViewHolders have the same stable ID. Stable IDs in your adapter MUST BE unique and SHOULD NOT change.

Note: this is an adapter with 3 viewholders

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: @MikeM. thanks for your reply, i forgot to post the error and now is updated the question can you please take a look again ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your view holders have different ids. 
As the error is telling you that all the view holders have the same id `id=43916` i.e All the 3 `ViewHolders` have the same id.

Please double check your view holder ids.

Comment: Viewholders have already different id in my code, the problem is because they have the same stable id that we set for RecyclerView @intellignt_idiot

Answer (score 0):

All you need is different IDs for the viewHolders you can simply write

```
override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long = position
```

position is unique for each element